# Remain on same TabPanel after Refresh on React

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <AppBar position="static">
                <Tabs
                variant="fullWidth"
                value={value}
                onChange={handleChange}
                aria-label="nav tabs example"
                >
                <LinkTab label="Overview" href="/drafts" {...a11yProps(0)} />
                <LinkTab label="Stocks" href="/trash" {...a11yProps(1)} />
                <LinkTab label="Data" href="/spam" {...a11yProps(2)} />
                </Tabs>
            </AppBar>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
              <OverviewContainer />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
              <StocksContainer />
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
              <AnalyticsContainer />
            </TabPanel>
            
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
```

This is the code for the root App. This is what my app [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XpTG.jpg)

If I refresh while im on stocks tab, it will revert to Overview Tab. I tried having separate routes/urls for each tab but it didnt really work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: you should try url hash and on refresh complete get hash value from url and set in tabs default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I ended up creating a component that stores current tab to localStorage

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const useStickyState = (defaultValue, key) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(() => {
    const stickyValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    return stickyValue !== null
      ? JSON.parse(stickyValue)
      : defaultValue;
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);
  return [value, setValue];
}

  export {useStickyState}
```